# another simple PHP page

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a simple PHP page that will Display a number starting with 0. It will then ask for a number input, then add the inputted number to the beginning number. and keep adding the number that is input in the text box. Here's what I have so far... I can get the first variable initialized and get the input from a form box. I just can't seem to add them together and keep a running total. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$_POST['number1'];
echo "Current number is ".$_POST['number1'];
echo "<br>";
echo "Enter your next number.<br>";
echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
echo "<input type='number' name='number2'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>";
echo "<br>";
echo "Your entered number is ".$_POST['number2']."<br>";
$sumtotal = $_POST['number1'] + $_POST['$number2'];
echo "Your new total is ".$sumtotal;
$_POST['number1'] == $_POST['number2'];
?>
```

Comment: You may want to hold the first number in a hidden input and then you can add them after submit and then the new number gets stored in the same hidden input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *input type **HIDDEN***:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$total=$_POST['number1']+$_POST['number2'];
echo "Your entered number is ".$_POST['number2']."<br>";
}

else {
$total=0;
}

echo "Current total number is ".$total;
echo "<br>";
echo "Enter your number.<br>";
echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='number1' value='$total'>";
echo "<input type='number' name='number2'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>";
echo "</form><br>";

echo "Your new total is ".$total;

?>
```

Using ***SESSION***:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION["total"])){
$_SESSION["total"]=0;
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$total=$_SESSION["total"];
$total=$total+$_POST['number2'];
$_SESSION["total"]=$total;
echo "Your entered number is ".$_POST['number2']."<br>";
}

echo "Current total number is ".$_SESSION['total'];
echo "<br>";
echo "Enter your number.<br>";
echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
echo "<input type='number' name='number2'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>";
echo "</form><br>";

echo "Your new total is ".$_SESSION['total'];
?>
```

Both works and have the same output, but with different approach from one another.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another hidden input field that keeps the last number that was posted by you.

```
<input style="display: none" name="tmp_number" value="<?php echo $tmp_number; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (edited for all details and errors)

```
<?php
$input = $sum = 0;
if (isset($_POST)) {
  $input = $_POST['number1'];
  $prev_sum = $_POST['prev'];
  $sum = $input + $prev_sum;
}
echo "Current number is ".$input;
echo "<br>";
echo "Enter your next number.<br>";
echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
echo "<input type='number' name='number1'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='prev' value='$sum' >";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>";
echo "<br>";
echo "Your entered number is ".$_POST['number1']."<br>";
echo "Your new total is ".$sum;
?>
```

Comment: This is what I'm working towards, These are the errors I get...
Notice: Undefined index: prev on line 4.
Notice: Undefined index: prev_num on line 12

also the numbers don't keep the totals. It just keeps displaying the inputted number in all variables.

Comment: Sorry my fault I forgot the input name

Comment: All the errors go away after you enter a number the first time. When the page first loads number1 and prev all give undefined errors... still having trouble with the $sum keeping a running total.

Comment: Updated my answer for all details and error either for the first time running or next time